# What is the best combat tracker for Android?

Tags: dnd-4e, tools

Just got a new Android phone, and I am wondering whether there is a good (preferably free) combat tracker.

Some criteria:

- Track player/monster defenses and HP
- Roll initiative for mobs and allow input for PCs initiative
- Support delaying turns
- Track status effects and ongoing damage

Some bonus features and things that would be nice, but aren't absolutes:

- Import monster stats/powers from DDI
- Play4e integration
- Load encounters built in InCombat

Comment: I doubt there is anything usable for tracking combat on the DM side (as opposed to something like iplay4e.com for a single PC). Maybe broaden your question to include the Android tablet platform?

Answer (score 5):

I've tried the free version of "Combat Assistant", and it seems the paid version will cover your main criteria to an extent.  However, I've found it buggy when there are too many effects active at once.  I hope it helps.

Comment: I've played with it a bit. the free version has no persistence which is annoying, I understand that is in the paid version.

Comment: Also welcome to RPG.SE and good first answer. Please have a look at our [FAQ] when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using the mobile version of the iPlay4e website?

Comment: I'm looking for something on the DM side rather than the player side. Iplay4e uses InCombat for its DM side and they do not have a native mobile interface...